# cannot call method 'then' on undefined sequelize error

Tags: promise, sequelize.js

I am returning a promise inside a function and and the handling the promise outside the function but I am getting cannot call method 'then' on undefined error. Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong or how can this be fixed.

```
function getMeterReadingByMeterIdandDate(sequelize, Dials, Meter, Server, meter_id, date){
   getNameByMeterId(sequelize, Meter, meter_id)
  .then(function(meter){
    getServerIdByMeterId(sequelize, Server, meter_id)
    .then(function(server){
      var name = meter[0].meter_id;
      var channel = "Ch"+name.substr(-1);
      var serialNumber = parseInt(name.substr(0,12));
      console.log({name:name,channel:channel,serialNumber:serialNumber});
      var server_id = server[0].server_id;
      return sequelize.query("select SUM(?) as total from dial?s where RealReadDate <= ? and SN = ?",
      {
        model:Dials[server_id],
        replacements:[channel, server_id, date.toISOString(), serialNumber],
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      });
    });
  });
}


function getStartMeterReadingByMeterIdAndBillingId(sequelize, Dials, Billings, Meter, Server, meter_id, billing_id){
   getStartDateByBillingId(sequelize,Billings,billing_id)
  .then(function(date){
    return getMeterReadingByMeterIdandDate(sequelize, Dials, Meter, Server, meter_id, date[0].start_date);
  });
}

 getStartMeterReadingByMeterIdAndBillingId(sequelize, Dials, Billings, Meter, Servers, meter.id, billing_id)
            .then(function(current_date_result){
              meter_obj.current = current_date_result[0].total;
});
```

I am getting cannot call method 'then' error when I function `callgetStartMeterReadingByMeterIdAndBillingId`  . Are we allowed to return Sequelize promises like than and then handle then else where by using the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `getStartMeterReadingByMeterIdAndBillingId`function does not return a promise based on your code example.

Assuming that `getStartDateByBillingId` returns a promise, you should change the code to:

```
function getStartMeterReadingByMeterIdAndBillingId(sequelize, Dials, Billings, Meter, Server, meter_id, billing_id){
   return getStartDateByBillingId(sequelize,Billings,billing_id)
  .then(function(date){
    return getMeterReadingByMeterIdandDate(sequelize, Dials, Meter, Server, meter_id, date[0].start_date);
  });
}
```

Comment: and this still may not get the result you want, because getMeterReadingByMeterIdandDate also does not return anything.